# How to create UIViewController (and controls) before (without) showing the controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

At startup of my app, I want to create an UIViewController and is controls. But I don't want to show it.

This is just a status view controller of certain activity that I wish to show only when required. But the status needs to be updated in background. So the controls need to be initialised without the need to call ShowViewController or PresentViewController.

Please help.

*Update*

Ok, some more information. I have a sync thread in the background that keeps posting status about the connection etc to this UIViewController. When the user launches the app, he may not want to see the status. While the sync is going on, if the user launches the UIViewController, he should be able to see the "Ongoing" status. So it is not a one time status that I can store in static object and show on view creation. The status will keep changing while the sync is going on. I am new to iOS programming.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Why you are updating  `UIViewController and is controls` to background ?, On certain activity you should directly pass the value to show to controls viewcontroller or store it globally and fetch them while you are showing Controls view controller

Comment: Rather than making this massively more complex than it needs to be (dealing with UI in background threads). Why not simply store the data somewhere and have this viewController fetch it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. Yes, you all are right that the viewController must fetch from some data. Request you to please let me know if what I am asking is technically possible. If so, how?

Comment: @GautamJain Your question is basically "how do I write my app?". This is much too broad. Please update this question or ask new ones giving explicit areas your'e having problems with, and what you've tried to solve them.

Answer (score -1):

You should store the status (or things to see for different things happened) in a static object. And prepare the ViewController that displays things according to this static object, changing the UIElement properties in viewWillAppear method. Once you changed the status and wish to popup the view just initialize the ViewController by PresentViewController.

Comment: Thanks Samson. Added one paragraph to my question with more details.